# How to get both quests from Romero?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I am playing Vampire the Masquerade: Bloodlines with community (unofficial) plus patch v8.4.2, and I am attempting to achieve both the "Pimpin' for Romero" and "You Only Die Once A Night" quests that he provides.

I completed "You Only Die Once A Night" and attempted to return to Romero, but Romero is gone. His doors are unlocked but he is not on the couch. I loaded an earlier game and completed "Pimpin' for Romero", but now Romero doesn't offer me the "You Only Die Once A Night" quest.

I have the console activated if it's a glitch. Is there any way to complete both of these quests for max XP?

Answer (score 5):

**You may only complete one of the two quests** without hacking the game. (as of [community patch v8.4.2](http://www.patches-scrolls.com/dl.php?file=VTMBup842.exe))

**Pimpin' For Romero** requires that you find someone who will have sex with Romero (or do it yourself if you are a female).

**You Only Die Once a Night** requires guarding the cemetery while Romero goes to find sex on his own.

They both achieve the same goal as far as the storyline is concerned, so once one is complete, the other is no longer necessary and therefore not available. Though, I bet he wouldn't mind a second go. :P

---

**As for Romero not returning** after "You Only Die Once a Night", see the following quote:

> If you manage to keep the zombies inside for 5 minutes, Romero will come back 
>   and you'll complete the quest (3 XP).

Which would lead one to assume that he will *not* come back if you fail this quest. Seeing as "You Only Die Once a Night" can be very difficult without the Celerity skill, there is a good chance that you may fail it repeatedly.

Additionally, there are several [patch notes](http://tessmage.com/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=57843.0) surrounding Romero not returning after the "You Only Die Once a Night" quest, one of which being:

> 498.Removed xp for Romero loving after zombie quest but made him return **(WESP BROKE)**

**WESP** being the author of most of the VTMB patches including 8.4.2. (I believe)

This note may also mean that there is no bonus XP to be had even if you do complete both quests.

There are [previous notes](http://tessmage.com/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=57843.0) of Romero's return being broken as well. It is possible that this is one issue that was created between two different modder's work, and may not have been resolved since. Also note that seeing as there have been many different patches put out by many different authors over the years, not all patch notes will be applicable to all patches, and old changes may be outdated.

---

Sources:

- [You Only Die Once a Night](http://www.gamebanshee.com/vampirebloodlines/walkthrough/youonlydieonceanight.php)
- [Pimpin' For Romero](http://www.gamebanshee.com/vampirebloodlines/walkthrough/pimpinforromero.php)
- [Full Walkthrough](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/914819-vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines/faqs/43148) (Search "SIDE QUEST: PIMPIN' FOR ROMERO")
- [Patch notes](http://tessmage.com/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=57843.0)
- Personal Experience

Comment: I completed you only die once a night successfully it took several tries without celerity but I did it. I read that with this plus patch you should be able to return to Romero and find him sitting on the couch. When you talk to him he says he wants some company (after the zombies he says he went to get a six pack not a hooker). But his house is empty.

Comment: @Mr.DeLioncourt There are several patch notes surrounding Romero not returning after the "You Only Die Once a Night" quest, one of which being: "498. Removed xp for Romero loving after zombie quest but made him return   (WESP BROKE)" There are previous notes of his return being broken as well. It is possible that this is one issue that was created between two different modder's work, and may not have been resolved since. This note was made in 2008.
Source: http://www.tessmage.com/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=57843.0

Comment: @Mr.DeLioncourt It is also worth noting that there have been many patches over the years by many different people, and many different versions of patches. Old patch notes may be outdated, and said changes (such as getting beer instead of getting laid) may no longer exist. Romero not returning, however, may simply be a bug. 8.4.2 *is* only a little over a month old, after all.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I think it's amazing that a 9 year old game still has so many people playing it to where new patches adding more material are being released on what looks like a near monthly basis!

Comment: @Mr.DeLioncourt Not a problem! Yeah, I too think it's pretty impressive. When I first heard that it was coming out on the Source engine (an alpha build) even before Half-Life 2, I did not expect it to be as good as it was. I certainly never expected people to still be doing work on it in 2013!